# "He concluded his speech with the words 'XXXX'": is "the words" mandatory?

Tags: syntax

Talking about a musician, for instance, the construction "He concluded his speech with the words 'and that's a great song'" seems common.

In the context of an essay, potential article, is "He concluded his speech with 'and that's a great song'" acceptable?

Comment: Acceptable to whom? The grammar and meaning are good, but depending on the context, it may be inappropriate style. In general on this site, please tell us as much as you can about the context so we don't have to ask you in the comments before answering

Comment: Here, acceptable in an essay / potential article. On the context of the sentence itself, "he" could be a musician, concluding his speech with [the words] "and that's a great song."

Comment: I mean, please add this information to the question by using the "Edit" button under it

Comment: I just did, but am quite curious, to be honest, as to how the context can be so influential in this precise case.

Comment: If it's spoken, then the audience cannot hear the quotation marks around the quote, and it might sound odd. In writing, people will understand it because of the visible quotes.

Comment: Very good point indeed! Thanks